# Print Mac OS' Photobook

Tags: macos, photos

I have created a photo book via Mac's Photos. How can I print it out? Basically, I would like to get a physical photo book from the digital one.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way would be to click the button top right marked "Buy Book", fill in the details, pay & Apple will send it to you.

If you want to attempt to do it yourself, or can find a service cheaper than Apple, then right click in the space between the individual pages & Save as PDF. Send that file to your print service.